# Redirect from HTML page to PHP page

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a simple redirect to a `php` page from the `html` page, but it generates an error that I can't understand, yet the `php` page only contains you simple `html` with just a small display, see at underneath.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="./traitement.php" method="post">
      <p>
        <label for="nom">Nom</label>
        <input type="text" name="nom" id="nom" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="submit" value="valider" />
      </p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

traitement.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p style="text-align: center;">   
Validated form
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

**error generated:**
This page is not available at the moment If the problem persists, contact the site owner.
HTTP ERROR 405

Comment: 405 means that HTTP method is not allowed (in this case, it seems like you're not allowed to make a POST request to it). Are you using some framework, or having some restrictions on your web server?

Comment: not as far as I know because I'm a novice and I don't even know how the configuration is done

Comment: Something is blocking the POST request anyway. Unfortunately, the posted code doesn't give us enough info to give any suggestions.

Comment: Is there any possible solution

Comment: Sure, you can find out what's causing it and fix that. But as I said, there isn't enough info for us to know what it is. Have you checked with the people that set everything up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to share the solution that I applied and which still worked before assigning {problem solved} it may be that it can help good brief.. when you are working with vs code and you are not using an apache server for example, you should open a new terminal and type the command like php -S Domain_Name {of your choice}. for example for me: php -S 127.0.0.1:5500 however I opted for 127.0.0.1:5500 since when I run my index.html I am redirected to my page containing my form with the domain name 127.0 .0.1:5500/index.html and I would like once I click on the validate button to be redirected to a php page while keeping the 127.0.0.1:5500 so I would not have to modify the url to display my php page, that is to say that if I had opted for: php -S localhost:8080 it would have been necessary to replace the 127.0.0:5500 in localhost:8080/processing.php to display my php page afterwards have made my click. On the other hand, when you use an apache server, it's easy to implement because you already have a server at your disposal that you need to start in advance.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).